# Pre-load fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment *SettingsFragment* that holds a complex layout and takes 3 seconds to load. I would therefore like to preload it at the time of starting the app, but only show it once the user has clicked on the settings menu item. Any idea how that could be accomplished? Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.addDevice:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, scanFragment, "ScanFragment")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, settingsFragment, "SettingsFragment")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
        case R.id.close:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .popBackStack();

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTopToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);

    settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    scanFragment = new ScanFragment();
```

Comment: It might be best to work out why it takes 3 seconds in the first place. That sounds like an awful lot of time. Also preloading a settings screen would surely be a bad idea as 90% of the time, the user wouldn't even access the settings at all. Big waste of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The main purpose of the app is the adjustment of settings, so no concerns in that regard. As to why it takes three seconds I can say that the fragment loads a viewPager which consists of 3-4 pages, each having around 40-50 buttons, icons and textviews.

Comment: The `ViewPager` should only load a single off screen page initially so that shouldn't be so much of an issue. Are you not able to use a`RecyclerView` for the content? Or is it not list-style content?

Comment: I have set the OffScreenPageLimit to 4 to ensure smooth transitions when sliding. That means the inflation of all pages is done at the beginning, which is why it takes so long. RecyclerView is not suitable I think as each row is different in its layout. Ideally the fragment would load when the app is started and then remain hidden in cache until the user needs it.